# Problem with LidR an Macbook m1 2021 library(lidR) lidR 4.0.1 using 1 threads

Tags: r, lidr

I am trying to use the LidR package but I get the following error when installing the package.

```
library(lidR)
lidR 4.0.1 using 1 threads. Help on <gis.stackexchange.com>. Bug report on <github.com/r-lidar/lidR>.
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error.

```
> library(lidR)
lidR 4.0.1 using 2 threads. Help on <gis.stackexchange.com>. Bug report on <github.com/r-lidar/lidR>.
```

It is telling you how many CPU threads it will use (in my case 2, in yours 1), where to get help with the package (here) and how to report bugs if you find any. These are all normal messages from when you attach (not install) the package.

If you don't want to see them then wrap the call in `suppressPackageStartupMessages`:

```
> suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lidR))
>
```

Comment: And you have 1 thread because, as far as I know, C++ parallelism with OpenMP is not supported on MacOS.